# Unable to configure network on Debian Server

Tags: debian

I was installing Debian 9 on the server, but unfortunately I am unable to get the internet connection. Below is the interfaces configuration.

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback 
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
  address 10.0.xxx.xx/24
  gateway 10.0.xxx.x
  dns-nameservers 202.x.x.x
```

Result for ifconfig:

```
lo, inet 127.0.0.1 / netmask 255.0.0.0
```

SSH from other server: Timeout, cannot connect - Port 22 
Route -n: empty 
ifup eno1: RTNETLINK answer: File exist, failed to bring up eno1.

And I did some testing as well.

```
sudo ifup --ignore-errors eno1

>> Output: Failed to load ... 
   RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
   RTNETLINK answers: Network is down

ifdown --force --verbose eno1 && ifup --force --verbose eno1

>> Output: ifdown: configuring interface eno1=eno1 (inet)
   /bin/run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-down.d
   run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-down.d/upstart/bin/ip route del default via 10.0.106.1 dev eno1 2>&1 1>/dev/null ||true
   RTNETLINK answers: No such process
   /bin/ip link set dev eno1 down
```

But After i have restarted the service, I still cant get internet access. Anyone encounter this before?

Comment: it is missing the netmask

Comment: subnet mask 255.255.255.0

Comment: the address is wrong.

Comment: Giacomo, may i know which address is wrong? the address 10.0.xxx.xx is the IP assigned to the server. Is that correct? Or I should put other?

Or are you referring to the subnet mask address is wrong?

Comment: You need to put an IP, so without the `/24`. Remove also dns-nameservers (not needed, better to keep nameservers in own resolver configuration).

Comment: Giacomo, Thanks, I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Can you ping the gateway address? Have you got the _resolvconf_ package installed? What's in `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: -- Not able to ping the gateway from the Debian server.  
"resolconf" have not, not sure how to use it?

Comment: On my local vm, I installed the resolvconf, and the file in /etc/resolv.conf displaying nameserver 10.0.2.1.... kindly advise.

Comment: I also found this online saying that I should add this line below to the conf file. 
[code] allow-hotplug eno1[/code] does anyone knows if it is correct.

Comment: I asked about _resolvconf_ because `dns-nameservers` is superfluous unless you actually use _resolvconf_. If you don't know better, I recommend removing both the _resolvconf_ package and the `dns-nameservers` setting, and configuring your resolver in `/etc/resolv.conf` by hand. However, the above won't help until you can ping your gateway at least. Please include the output of `ip a` into your question. Don't use `allow-hotplug` on a server, stay with `auto`. And refer (@) to my name in your reply comment so that I get notified.

Comment: @FerencWágner , in the 'resolv.conf' file contains the domains and nameserver listing. Remove the package? As in the file? ...... the 'allow-hotplug' has been removed.

Comment: No, purge the package as in `apt purge resolvconf`. How do you know your gateway address? And again: please edit the output of the `ip a` command into your question.

Comment: @FerencWágner ... "resolvconf" not installed, so not removed. The gateway address was defined during the installation.

Comment: @FerencWágner, I am still unable to ping my default gateway still. I have tried using mine and google gateway. 
In /etc/resolv.conf
>> nameserver 8.8.8.8

Comment: Don't confuse gateway and DNS resolver addresses, and please kindly answer my questions if you expect any further help.

Comment: @FerencWágner, sorry which question i missed out? I am not sure about the DNS resolver add...

Comment: You didn't provide the output of `ip a` and didn't tell how you know your gateway address.

Comment: @FerencWágner you mean output of ifconfig ? 
Gateway is provided by the ISP.

Comment: To be honest, I'm losing patience... I wrote "the output of `ip a`" and I mean the output of `ip a`, really. But what do you mean by "gateway is provided by the ISP"? Did they tell you to set the gateway address to 10.0.2.1 (or whatever) manually? Don't they provide DHCP (automatic configuration) or PPPoE?

Comment: Sorry some correction, the gateway was set on the router. Setting of the gateway address is not by us, was done by the other department. No DHCP, the server connection was configured to Static IP.

Comment: What router? You'd better negotiate with that "other department", I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You have set the netmask using CIDR notation, it needs the netmask set as follows:

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback 
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
  address 10.0.xxx.xx
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 10.0.xxx.x
  dns-nameservers 202.x.x.x
```

Edit: Debian 9 will in fact accept CIDR notation in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, so you must have another issue.
I'd suggest setting the network settings manually and verifying you have connectivity, then adjust `/etc/network/interfaces` to reflect your working network settings.

Comment: Debian 9 (stretch) most certainly understands the CIDR notation in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Even Debian 8 (jessie) does.

Comment: I have input as suggested and restarted. But it shows "Network not configure" error. Any idea?